# When gets CompanionDeviceManager.Callback#onFailure called

Tags: android

I am currently implementing companion device pairing and I am wondering when the CompanionDeviceManager.Callback#onFailure is called. The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/companion/CompanionDeviceManager.Callback#onFailure(java.lang.CharSequence)) is not really specific ("Invoked if the association could not be created").

If possible I would provide our users a instruction what has failed. Does anyone know a little bit more here?

BR
Andreas